# SSRS date parameters with Oracle data source

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

I have a ssrs report with oracle data source and two date parameters: startdate and enddate, query like this:

```
select * from mytbl
where reportdate between :startdate and :enddate
```

Both parameters are datetime, I have to handle parameter is null also.

```
select * from mytbl
where reportdate between to_date(NVL(:StartDate, '01-JAN-1900'), 'DD-MON-yyyy') AND to_date(NVL(:EndDate, '31-DEC-9999'), 'DD-MON-yyyy')
```

But the report only works when both parameters are null. It shows no data when I input some date in the startdate and enddate parameters.

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after:

```
select *
from   mytbl
where  reportdate between nvl(:startdate, to_date('01/01/1900', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                  and     nvl(:enddate, to_date('31/12/9999', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```